How can I install tensorflow and keras for Python 3.10.2?
I tried to install the tensorflow and keras with anaconda, but I did not succeed. The advice given at this link text did not help. Could you describe in detail how to install the library for Python 3.10.2. Additional info: Windows 10, x64, Intel(R) Pentium(R) Gold G6400 CPU.
Thank you!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\NN1\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\NN1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\NN1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tf2.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_tf2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).


To resolve the issue of installing TensorFlow and Keras on Python 3.10.2 in Anaconda on Windows 10,Creating a clean environment helps avoid conflicts. Open Anaconda Prompt and run:conda create -n tf_env python=3.10.2,Activate the new environment:conda activate tf_envEnsure you have the latest version of Conda:conda update conda

Install TensorFlow:-pip install tensorflow==2.15.0,Please follow this steps.
